# arm_navigation : planner_service_name v.s. planner_id

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The former one belongs to

```
arm_navigation_msgs::action_goal.planner_service_name
```

The latter one belongs to

```
arm_navigation_msgs::action_goal.motion_plan_request.planner_id
```

According to the following tutorial:

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/MoveArmJointGoal
```

The planner_id is different from the planner_service_name since some planning libraries might offer different types of planners within the same service call

Then I would like to ask what is the planner_id for the default ompl planner? Where is it specified(from which file or parameter)?

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42891/arm_navigation-:-planner_service_name-v.s.-planner_id/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-07**:
interesting question. in the planning configuration yaml file we can fill in several planners. i guess these ids are corresponding to those planners there and maybe increase from 0 monotonously

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-09-08**:
What and where is that yaml config file? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here you find some example planner configurations:

http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/planning_environment/html/ (scroll down a bit)

And here in the source code you can find the currently available planners via the OMPL ROS interface (look at the private member functions):

http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/ompl_ros_interface/html/classompl__ros__interface_1_1OmplRosPlanningGroup.html

Further than that I have been successfully using the CHOMP planner, which is not part of OMPL.

**/edit:**

Albert, regarding your comment:
My planner configuration was created automatically by the [planning description configuration wizard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard). The created configuration file looks similar to [this one for the pr2](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/stacks/pr2_arm_navigation/branches/arm_navigation_metrics/pr2_arm_navigation_planning/config/ompl_planning.yaml?rev=52106).
I'm loading those parameters like this:

```
  <node pkg="ompl_ros_interface" type="ompl_ros" name="ompl_planning">
        <param name="default_planner_config" type="string" value="SBLkConfig1" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find your_robots_arm_navigation_pkg)/config/ompl_planning.yaml" />
  </node>
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-09-12**:
I've read the pages, thanks. Besides, I tried to find the yaml file in the planning_environment package , and inspected the launch file pr2_3dnav/right_arm_navigation.launch and the launch file included by it, but I couldn't find the rosparam tag that included the correct yaml.